# Inserting Sublime Text snippets without a leading space

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets

I have a code snippet whose code often gets tacked onto the end of some text. Here is the snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
\textsubscript{$1}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>ts</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

The typical use case for this is when I'm writing a document in LaTeX and need to subscript something in text mode; e.g., `NP\textsubcript{count}`. In every case the snippet will be appended to the previous word.

The problem I'm having is that Sublime only triggers the completion when the tab trigger (`ts`) appears on its own -- not when it is appended to a word. Usually this is exactly the behavior I want, but in this case I need there to be no space between, e.g., `NP` and `\textsubscript{count}`. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: I had this problem before and I removed the \ character from the snippet, but then you would have to write `NP\ts`. Another alternative is expand ts to `{$1}\textsubscript{$2}` so you can write previous text if you want. I hope someone posts a real solution for this problem without using plugins.

Comment: @sergioFC Thanks for the tip about removing the \ from the snippet. That's a nice workaround.